# Changing View Controllers on startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

When my app launches for the first time, I want it to be directed to SettingsViewController and from next launch, I want it to be directed to MainViewController

I am not using XIB files, I am using storyboards XCODE 5.1 and iOS7.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: store a flag in nsuserdefaults to know it's the first time. in viewdidapear you can do if(firsttime), push or present your settings vc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other suggestions will work and are probably right, however when I did it that way in the past, tbh it looks messy when the app opens for the first time and you get an instant push animation.

What you can do is switch out your root view controller in your AppDelegate so the user does not see any navigations on first launch, your settings will show and when they are finished with the settings perform a modal segue to your main view controller.

For me it looks better. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ( ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SettingsShown"] )
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SettingsShown"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Storyboard setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem, you should just do it in your appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, 
On the first time you prepareForSegue to your Settings then you stock a value wherever you want (file, NSUserDefaults) to keep in mind you already did then on the same appDelegate you add an if to check this value.

This method:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Use this to set :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:variable forKey:@"variable"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And then this to get :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"yourVariable"]
```

Job is done.

Answer (score 0):

the entry point in the storyboard should be the `MainViewController` in in `ViewDidLoad` it would check if the settings is missing it would `PerformSegue` to the settingsViewController.

Also it is a good idea to give the user an option to get back to the settings through a button or something.